UBUNTU 24.04 double routes - how?
Hya,
after installing 24.04 and restoring networking files (ifconfig, dnsmasq, etc), i found the my routing table shows the following:
root@wolke:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.254   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth1
192.168.28.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wap0
192.168.80.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0


My /etc/network/interfaces file:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
dns-nameservers 192.168.80.4

auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.80.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway eth1
broadcst 192.168.80.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.80.4
dns-search mydomain

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
gateway eth1
dns-nameservers 192.168.80.4
dns-search mydomain

# The WLAN  network interface
auto wap0
iface wap0 inet static
address 192.168.28.4
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway eth1
broadcst 192.168.28.255
dns-nameservers 192.168.80.4
#dns-search mydomain


Is there any other configuration file to check?
Thx in advance!

Check /etc/netplan and /etc/NetworkManager and /etc/systemd/networkd.conf and /etc/systemd/networkd.conf.d/. Best you check which of these are used. Usually it is NetworkManager, but as there is still a /etc/network/interfaces on your systems, it seems your ubuntu was upgraded several times now.
